# Solar requirements for 5000W equivalent system

Tags: solar-energy

I currently run a fridge-freezer and larger freezer, some lights and computers off of a 5000W, 220V to 110V (50 Hz) transformer. I am trying to run that on off-grid solar instead of using the transformer.

1. Would a 5000W (pure sine wave) inverter be able to run the same loads as the 5000W transformer?
2. What size battery bank (i.e. how many Ah) on a 24V setup would be needed? (Assuming constant charge from solar & wind sources.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I currently run a fridge-freezer and larger freezer, some lights and computers off of a 5000W, 220V to 110V (50 Hz) transformer.

It sounds as though a 1 kW system should be adequate.

> Q1. Would a 5000W (pure sine wave) inverter be able to run the same loads as the 5000W transformer?

Yes.

> Q2. What size battery bank how many (Ah) on a 24v setup would be needed?

You haven't specified the required run time from the batteries.

- Work out the energy storage your load requires in watt-hours (Wh) for the required run time.
- Since power = voltage × current (*P = VI*) and energy, *E = P × t* you can work out the ideal battery capacity from \$ Ah = \frac E V \frac 1 {Eff} \$ where *Eff* is the efficiency of your inverter.

> ... (assuming constant charge from solar & Wind sources).

This makes it sound as though you don't require any storage.

Answer (score 1):

### Strictly in terms of the science...

a 5 kVA transformer can carry a great deal more than 5kw intermittently...   Wires and transformers are rated at 125% of continuous service, and the limiting factor is heat. The copper is fairly massive and it takes time for overheat to occur. there’s no limit to the overload if it’s short enough.  100kVA would be possible for a short transient.

Your house wiring is the same way, and your breakers are designed to tolerate overloads that the wire can handle.

Silicon cannot endure overload like that.

Still, in your case, you are probably doing great.  None of your loads will add up to nearly 5000W, unless your computers are stupidly large.

**Keep in mind, when sizing a solar/battery system, it is far cheaper to replace  inefficient loads with efficient ones**, than to provision extra solar and battery for the inefficient loads.  So new MacBooks to replace the clunky old “PCs with 850W power supply”, can be part of the battery budget.  Ratty old fridges and freezers should also be given a careful energy review.